# How do I perform this query in both Mongo console and Mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to learn how to query Mongo in more advanced ways.  Let's say my data structure is this:

```
{ "_id" : "-bcktick-ajman-ae-292932", "asciiname" : "`Ajman", 
    "alternatenames" : [
    {
        "isolanguage" : "no",
        "alternateNameId" : 2698358,
        "alternateName" : "Ajman"
    },
    {
        "isolanguage" : "en",
        "alternateNameId" : 2698357,
        "alternateName" : "Ajman"
    }
  ]
}
```

So to find **`Ajman`** is easy:

```
db.cities.find({ "asciiname":"`Ajman" })
```

However, I want to find cities that only have an `isolanguage` of **en**.  You'll notice the `isolanguage` is in the **alternatenames** array.

But I can't seem to find the correct syntax in either the client or **mongoid**

Either one (or both) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `$elemMatch` keyword:

```
db.cities.find(
  { 'alternatenames' : {
       $elemMatch: { isolanguage: 'en'} 
     } 
})
```

Currently, Mongoid does not have a helper for `$elemMatch` so you have to pass in the raw query:

```
City.where({ :alternatenames => { '$elemMatch' => { :isolanguage => 'en' } } })
```

More info here on `$elemMatch` here:

- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch
- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29

More info on Mongoid support for `$elemMatch` here:

- http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/8648b451e3957e12
- https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/750

Comment: Worked PERFECTLY on both counts.  Thanks!

Comment: @bowsersenior would this query work with mongoid 2, or only with 3?

Comment: @thatmiddleway It should work with any Mongoid version because you are passing in a raw Mongo query. I haven't tested in Mongoid 3, though. Please let me know how it goes.